# How do I draw a cloud with polygons?

Tags: java, swing, drawing, polygon

In my course notes my lecturer explains how to make a triangle but that is about where the explanation ends. I need to draw a cloud so is there a way I can make the edges round? Or is there a better way to approach this?

```
package polygon;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Polygon;

public class PanelPoly extends javax.swing.JPanel {

   int[] xWaarden = {100,210,360};
   int[] yWaarden = {170,60,170};
   Polygon triangle = new Polygon(xWaarden, yWaarden,xWaarden.length);

   public PanelPoly() {

   }

   public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
       super.paintComponent(g);
       g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
       g.fillPolygon(triangle);
   }


    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(this);
        this.setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGap(0, 400, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGap(0, 300, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        );
    }// </editor-fold>                        
    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    // End of variables declaration                   
}
```

Comment: Take a look at the other methods of the `Graphics` class. I would recommend the methods `fillOval(...)` and `drawOval(...)` (for drawing outlines). The full list of available methods you will find here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `java.awt.geom.Area`. Create multiple areas from several ovals and organize intersections of the circles.

Or you can see `Polygon` with rounded angles. See for example sources from here http://java-sl.com/shapes.html for the starts and regular polygons there is an approach how to round their angles.

That's simple example how to combine 2 ovals http://java-sl.com/tip_flatteningpathiterator_moving_shape.html